# ubuntu 12.04 installer does not recognize drive partitions

Tags: system-installation

I recently purchased a new HP Pavilion HPE desktop running Windows 7. I am trying to install a dual-boot system with 12.04. However, when I run the LiveCD I only get as far as the "Install" window where you can select the partitions for your drives. On the bottom where it says "device for boot loader installation" I have "/dev/sda" and cannot select any other devices.

All the options to change the drives are greyed out, most likely because there are no drives in the window. I partitioned my largest drive using the tools within Windows, then booted into the CD, but nothing shows up. I then used Gparted to change the new space from unallocated to an /ext2, and still nothing shows up.

The installer does not recognize anything, but when I go into an Ubuntu session and use the disk utility manager I can see the partitions I made. Anything I do has to be done outside of the installer.

I have no files on this new computer, so this is the perfect time to install a parallel OS. I would like avoid completely reinstalling Windows, however. I've been over the forums many times, but all the answers I've found have not worked for me. I also tried flagging the new, empty partition as boot, but that screwed Windows up.

Also, the WUBI installer hits the same point and quits. I know that the disk itself is fine because I just made another dual boot system on a Gateway PC. This makes me think something within this computer is preventing the installer from "seeing" the drives. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit in response: The main part of the partitioning window shows no partitions, everything is blank. There is no way to add partitions, and all the buttons are useless. I've tried defragging my drive multiple times, and I also used the same disk to dual-boot another PC with no problems, so it's not the disk, it's definitely the computer.

Comment: The boot loader needs to be installed to /dev/sda, so that is normal.  Does the main part of the partitioning window see the partitions?

Answer (score 4):

When the installer gives you the selection to install grub to `/dev/sda` only, that's normal. You see, in Linux, partitions and disks are represented this way:

- Disks are represented as an entry in `/dev` with no number at the end. `sda`s are SATA disks, `hda`s are PATA disks (CD drives are usually `cdrom`, `cd`, `cdrw`. Same for DVDs).
- Partitions, however, are represented as the device they are on (the above point) followed by a number. So, while `/dev/sda` is your *disk*, `/dev/sda1` is a partition on that disk.

The boot loader doesn't install to a partition -- it installs to a disk. That's why the install is asking whether you want to install on `/dev/sda`, which is a disk.

Answer (score 3):

I was having an identical problem also on an HP Pavilion machine. I booted Ubuntu from CD and wanted to move to a permanent installation (not trying to create a dual boot machine, actually, a pure Linux box). I created all of the partitions with GParted but the installation tool didn't see them. Interesting bit is that fdisk -l did not see the partitions either.

The fix was to run `sudo dmraid -rE` . Once that was done, the installation tool saw the hard disk.

In my case (Arthur Borsboom) this fix removes something related to Nvidia RAID (nvraid), which I have been using in the past for Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my old Dell that has fakeraid, after I swapped out a dead hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link [Ubuntu 12.10 installer does not detect drive partitions](http://akovid.blogspot.com/2012/11/ubuntu1210-installer-does-not-detect.html)

Hope it may help...

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I went into Rescue mode and dropped to a shell inside the installer.
Then ran the `sudo dmraid -rE` command as mentioned above because the system I'm using also has the nVidia Raid card.
Once that was done, the installer saw the drive just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful, if you can, briefly, explain how to get into rescue mode.

Comment: will the usage of this command jeopardize the functioning of the nvidia card on the windows partition?