# Ubuntu 13.04 Installation - Need Help!

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted

I am installing Ubuntu 13.04. I have the installation open on my screen and it runs fine until I get to a part called "Installation Type" which is basically where I choose a partition. I opened Gparted, deleted my Windows partition and made a brand new partition so the only partition there is on my hard drive is one ext4 partition that is flagged to boot and it has 500GB. I have another 500GB of unallocated space.

Basically when I get to this step of the installation, no partitions show up and when I press continue anyway it says this.

```
No root file system defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

> **My partition setup:**
>   /dev/sda1 - ntfs - HP_Recovery - 18GB, Unallocated - 450.43GB
>   /dev/sda4 - Extended - 452GB
>
> **Then attached to the Extended partition it says this underneath:**
>   unallocated - unallocated - 1MB
>   /dev/sda5 - ext4 - 452.89GB

Basically /dev/sda4 is the main partition I want to use and attached to it for some reason is a filesystem that's ext4 and a random unallocated one.

Any idea what I did wrong? I can give more information if needed.

> **Output of sudo fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x000a5604

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sda1            2048    38143999    19070976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda4   *  1003743230  1953523711   474890241    5 Extended /dev/sda5      1003745280  1953523711   474889216   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 8019 MB, 8019509248 bytes 247 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 15663104 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x000576ef

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdb1   *          62    15650907     7825423    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: Just saw that it says none of these are mounted. Im not an expert with partitions or GParted for that matter. But I do have common sense. Is this a problem, if so how do I "mount" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this screen, choose Something else

[image: Installation type screen]

Then you should click on your main Ubuntu partition then choose 'Change' from the small buttons at the bottom left, choose Ext4 journalling file system (or similar). You should then put a single `/` in the mount path field. This is your Root Filesystem that will be used for the storage of all data on your system (excluding USB drives, etc). Also, you should not have the partitions mounted while you are editing them.

Note: It is recommended to have an extra `swap` partition with the same size of your RAM, which is used as extra memory for your system. See here: [DiskSpace - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) and here: [Swap Faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

**EDIT:** Run the command `sudo dmraid -rE` in a terminal, then retry the installation. From this question: [ubuntu 12.04 installer does not recognize drive partitions](https://askubuntu.com/a/164720/176889)

Comment: I don't see anything saying change. But I get what your saying and that makes sense. I will keep looking for the small buttons but there aren't any buttons in the left.

Comment: Are you in 'Something else' mode or did you choose one of the other options

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mode. I just ran GParted from the menu.

Comment: OK, you need to click Install Ubuntu on your desktop then go into the screen which says 'Installation type' then choose something else at the bottom of the list.

Comment: It shows under the empty list of partitions a change button but if I click it, the install crashes. Same with anything else like if I press the + or - next to it. :/

Comment: I never got to a screen that looks like the image you attached. I choose my language, click continue and it brings me to the step I'm having trouble with.

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Heres an image of the thing I'm talking about.
http://tinypic.com/r/oqy7ig/5

Ill add the output to my post.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. There should also be a way to choose a simpler method of installation (in my screenshot) but you said you didn't have it

Comment: I added sudo fdisk -l's output in my post. Also sda5 or whatever, the one that is attached to the extended partition currently has 8gb of data on it, I think there is Linux on it, I don't know whats going on with it.

Comment: Can you try the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/a/164720/176889 or here (if you can afford to lose everything on your drive): http://akovid.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/ubuntu1210-installer-does-not-detect.html

Can you also try to mount the partitions (from Gparted right click menu) then retry

Comment: Woah I tried the command in the first link and ran the install again. Now it shows the page of the image you attached. Which one do I choose?

Comment: Use the `something else` one, select your /dev/sda4 then click change > from the list, Ext4 file (or similar) then set the mountpoint to `/`

Comment: Thanks so much man! I selected your answer as correct because this will reboot my computer. I will come back and let you know if all is good. I would give you +1 but it says I need 15 rep to do that :/

Comment: Wait, when I press continue it says to choose a partition for swap space since its recommended. - Nevermind I got it. I have 20GB for swap space. I have like 2tb anyways.

Comment: Glad I could help, and welcome to askubuntu.com