# No partitions recognised while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have decided to install Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 8, the OS I have currently installed and that I don't want to uninstall because I need some programs.

I have downloaded the ISO and burned it into a CD. Everything in the installation goes well until I have to choose where to install it. It doesn't recognise my Windows 8 and it sees my disk as if it was all empty space (500 GB).

What should I do to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Ultrabook? With Intel SRT? You need to turn that off and remove RAID meta-data. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred, did you link the wrong question?  That one doesn't say anything about raid.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo parted -l` and edit your question and paste in the output.

Comment: Is this the same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162631/ubuntu-12-04-installer-does-not-recognize-drive-partitions

Answer (score 0):

If the "Something Else" partitioning option is showing the disk as completely unpartitioned, then chances are you've run into a libparted bug that causes tools that use that library (such as the Ubuntu installer) to think the disk is empty when in fact the partition table is not to libparted's liking. This problem can often (but not always) be fixed by my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program, which is part of the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` (I don't recall which offhand) package in Ubuntu. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) for more on this problem.