# Ubuntu 13.10 Installer freezes on partition recognition on Alienware M17x

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on an Alienware M17x,

after bypassing the graphical problems with "nomodeset" (annoying!), I'm facing a rather different problem: I click on "Install Ubuntu", the guided installation progress reach the point where the partition, mount point etc. needs to be selected and...nothing.

In the partition selection menu it sees only dev/sda, but in the window where the actual way the disk is partitioned should appear nothing shows, it's blank.

I've tried to click on "change..." to try to force it to read something, but the installer simply quits. The button "change partition table" etcetera are greyed out (well, obviously, since no partition table has been read). What's that?

The Alienware has Windows 7 and legacy BIOS (so no UEFI here).

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I found that the a potential cause may be tied to some nvidia raid metadata (<http://askubuntu.com/questions/162631/ubuntu-12-04-installer-does-not-recognize-drive-partitions>) and that the solution may be to use `sudo dmraid -rE` to remove such metadata. The question is: may this jeopardize the functioning of my nvidia on my windows partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete answer to my question: for me it worked like a charm. Be aware though that every instance that make the OS prober query the partition table will remove the Windows partition from the bootloader and you will have to redo the remove dmraid & reactivate acceleration all over again!

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038121

Answer (score 0):

The installation problem is simply solved by opening a terminal and running:

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

...but this just leads to a boot problem.